# How to remove all vectors from a cell B which belong to A or which are contained in one vector from A?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

```
A = {[1 2 3 4],[22 55 78 84],[50 21 98 71],[10 15 16]};
B = {[2 4],[20 30 55],[16 15 10],[22 55 78]};
```

How to remove all vectors from a cell B which belong to A or which are contained in one vector from A?

**The desired result for my example**

```
out = {[20 30 55]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
out = B(~cellfun(@(y) any(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(y,x)), A)), B));
```

The explanation of the code is just saying in other words what you asked for: the inner `cellfun` detects if a vector of `B` is completely contained by one of the vectors of `A`, and the outer `cellfun` assembles these results for all `B` vectors. The resulting logical vector (the size of `B`) is negated, because you want the vectors that are unique to `B`, not the ones "embedded" in `A`.